# Using python script to close eclipse and update from svn

Tags: python, eclipse, svn, automation

I am new to python and the first project that I have has the following steps which should be executed through a python script run from command-line on a Mac:

(1) Close Eclipse.
(2) Update the code from svn
(3) Run a Ant deploy script

As I said I am very new to python and plan to learn as I go along coding the script. Any pointers/code would be helpful. I am using python 2.7.1.

Thanks!
Sameer

Comment: Do you want to close eclipse the hard way? Or should eclipse close in an orderly manner?

Comment: I would say close eclipse in an orderly manner. The preferred way would be to close a single project related to the svn update which would be done in the next step. I haven't found anything after googling though.

Answer (score 0):

Python's kinda the 'hard way' to do this. Eclipse has CLI scripting capabilities that you might be able to make use of. For example [update_standalone reference](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/update_standalone.html). Granted you have to play a bit in jar-land to do this, consider that literally nobody developing for Eclipse is going to lift a finger to make things easier for you - but if you play by their rules it's not as hard.